# DataGridView.HitTestInfo equivalent in Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Does anyone know if the Infragistics UltraGrid control provides functionality similar to that of DataGridView.HitTestInfo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.abstraction-systems.com/ttf/HTML/TTFactory_TaskBasedTutorials_UltraWinGrid.htm) out.

They don't convert the coordinates, but they use a special Infragistics grid event ([MouseEnterElement](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.v8.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraComponentControlManagerBase~MouseEnterElement_EV.html)) to get the element, which the mouse currently hovers over.

Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `.MousePosition` property which returns `System.Drawing.Point` and "Gets the position of the mouse cursor in screen coordinates" but I'm using an older version of their UltraWinGrid (2003).

They have a [free trial download](http://www.infragistics.com/downloads/default.aspx), so you could see if they've added it to their latest and greatest  :o)

Answer (score 0):

If you had a MouseEventHandler for the UltraGrid then you can do the following:

```
UltraGrid grid = (UltraGrid)sender;

UIElement element = grid.DisplayLayout.UIElement.ElementFromPoint(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
```

You can then cast the element depending on its expected type using element.GetContext():

```
 UltraGridCell cell = (UltraGridCell)element.GetContext(typeof(UltraGridCell));
```